# What exactly is the role and responsibility of an Agilist in an Agile scrum squad?

Tags: agile, squad

Our org is implementing SAFe framework and teams are now working in a squad.

I am a PO on a squad where my focus is managing the backload and priority, as per the org we need to have a Agilist.

**Questions:**

- Currently, I run daily standup, retros and  PI planning.
- What is the role and responsibilities of an Agilist?
- Can anyone on the squad be an agilist?
- Once we have Agilist, what exactly agilist will be doing on daily basis? Is agilist a full time role? Does it come with a lot of overhead work?

If anyone can help me understand the role of Agilist and daily duties that would be helpful.

Comment: Do a web search, or even better, ask the people that want to implement SAFe in your org how they see that role. There's a lot of variety in agile processes, and each team needs to adjust them as needed.

Comment: I tried but couldn't find any clear information online that goes over the roles and responsibility. On a high-level (irrespective of org requirement), what an agilist does on daily basis?

Answer (score 0):

"What is the role and responsibilities of an Agilist?"

Besides working as the ART's (Agile Release Train, which is team of agile teams.) coach, an agilist should promote the adoption of SAFe methods and principles within the ART. They should also oversee ART activities like System Demos, Scrum of Scrums, PI Planning, and Inspect and Adapt workshops, ensuring team coordination, openness, and cooperation, identifying roadblocks and eliminating them, and promoting an agile mindset and culture of continuous improvement.

"Can anyone on the squad be an agilist?"

Agilist should have experience and expertise in agile methodologies and SAFe practices, technically anyone with sufficient knowledge and willingness to take on the role can fulfill it.